# Confusion with making a dropdown menu clickable for mobile users

Tags: javascript, android, ios, css, html

Hey i'm having some trouble getting my drop down menu clickable. Everything is working fine in the hover state but i want it to be clickable for mobile users. Please see my code any help would be greatly appreciated. I want to keep the hover state for people using a PC but also want the click to be working for mobiles.

Many thanks
Sam

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.topnav').click(function() {
   $('.sub-nav').toggleClass('visible');
  });
 });
```

```css
.subnav ul.sub-nav{
  display: none;
}

.subnav ul.visible {
  display: block;
}

#headernav .tile:hover a{
  background-color:#fff;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px -1px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.51);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px -1px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.51);
  box-shadow: -1px -1px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.51);
  -webkit-transition:0.5s ease-in;
  -moz-transition:0.5s ease-in;
  -o-transition:0.5s ease-in;
}

#headernav .abouttile {
  width:13%;
  float: left;
  margin:0 3%;
  transition:0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition:0.5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition:0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition:0.5s ease-out;

}

#headernav .abouttile:hover{
  background-color:#fff;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  padding-bottom:10%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px -1px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.51);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px -1px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.51);
  box-shadow: -1px -1px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.51);
  -webkit-transition:0.5s ease-in;
  -moz-transition:0.5s ease-in;
  -o-transition:0.5s ease-in;
}
#headernav .projecttile {
  width:13%;
  float: left;
  margin:0 3%;
  transition:0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition:0.5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition:0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition:0.5s ease-out;

}

#headernav .projecttile:hover{
  background-color:#fff;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  padding-bottom:16%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px -1px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.51);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px -1px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.51);
  box-shadow: -1px -1px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.51);
  -webkit-transition:0.5s ease-in;
  -moz-transition:0.5s ease-in;
  -o-transition:0.5s ease-in;
}

#headernav .subnav ul{
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding:0.5%;
  width:auto;
  margin: 1.8% 0 0 0;
}

#headernav .subnav:hover ul{
  display:block;
}

#headernav .subnav ul li{
  background-color:transparent;
  width:100%;
  font-size:0.8em;
  line-height: 1.6;
  -webkit-transition:0.5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition:0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition:0.5s ease-out;
}

#headernav .subnav ul li:hover{
  opacity: 0.8;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight:bold;
  -webkit-transition:0.5s ease-in;
  -moz-transition:0.5s ease-in;
  -o-transition:0.5s ease-in;
}

.current{
    width:auto;
    padding: 5% 9%;
    margin: 0 18%;
    color:#222222;
    float:left;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px -1px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.51);
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px -1px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.51);
    box-shadow: -1px -1px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.51);
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.topnav{
  color:#222222;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:#222222;
  padding: 5% 9%;
  margin: 0 2%;
  float:left;
  -webkit-transition:0.5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition:0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition:0.5s ease-out;
}

.currenttile{
  width:18%;
  float: left;
  height:auto;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">

<div class="headerlogo">
 <img src="images/logo3.png">

</div>

<div id="headernav">

    <div class="currenttile">
        <a class="current" href="index.html">Home</a>
    </div>  
    <div class="abouttile">
      <div class="subnav">  
        <div class="topnav" href="about.html">About Us</div>
          <ul class="sub-nav">
            <a href="#"><li>The Organisation</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Our Goals</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Acheivements</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Partnerships</li></a>
          </ul>
      </div>  
    </div>
    <div class="projecttile">
      <div class="subnav">
        <div class="topnav" href="projects.html">Projects</div>
          <ul class="sub-nav">
            <a href="#"><li>Fuel Poverty</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Carers</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Education</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Sensory Garden</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Prayer Sessions</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Capacity Buildings</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Mental Health</li></a>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
      <div class="subnav">
        <a class="topnav" href="services.html">Services</a>
          <ul>
          
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile">
      <a class="topnav" href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Currently it looks like it's only enabled for click - I don't see any hover based actions.

Comment: All the CSS has the :hover states. Clicking isn't working at all

Comment: it's because mobile devices does handle hover differently. I would not rely on any type of hover solution for mobile devices.

Comment: Yeah thats why i want the dropdown to function on click but i'm not sure how to make it work

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.topnav').click(function() {
            $('.sub-nav').toggle();
        });
    });
```

this should do the trick